# Scrolling a painted line over a GridView

Tags: android, gridview, scroll, paint

I have a situation where I have drawn (painted) a line over a GridView. Thanks to excellent help from someone, I've overridden the dispatchPaint() method in a class that inherits from GridView. The grid in this case is actually a calendar, and more of the calendar is being drawn than actually shows on screen.

If I scroll the calendar (GridView) the painted line does not scroll with it. So I figure I either have to scroll the line myself, or else paint the line via some other method so that it's more tightly associated with the view.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Maybe you should consider using a different approach like setting one of the child's drawables or background drawable.  If that doesn't fit your needs, try a FrameLayout (or RelativeLayout).

Comment: Well, nothing else I've done has worked. I'll give the relative layout a try and see if that's a little more successful. Thanks for responding!